# Passing a WebService to a different class in flex

Tags: web-services, apache-flex

Ok I have a problem. I want to declare a webservice in .mxml and pass it to a function in a separate class. The problem: callresponder's lastresult never gets updated when the call is succesfully made.

Or I could be missing something to do with a CallResponder and AsyncToken in that 2nd class...

The code in  my.mxml

```
<fx:Declarations> 
    <myws:Myws id="ws" />       
</fx:Declarations>
<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    var myClass:MyClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.callWS(ws);
]]></fx:Script>
```

The code in myClass.as

```
public class MyClass
{               
    protected var cR:CallResponder = new CallResponder();       
    public function callWS(ws:Myws):void{
        var cR:CallResponder = new CallResponder();
        cR.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler);
        cR.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultHandler);
        cR.token = ws.MyCall(); 
    }
        private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
            cR.lastResult;  // --> this is undefined
            cR.token; // --> this is null
    }
}
```

I could actually read the result from the ResultEvent, but would prefer knowing why callresponder is not working. Any help or insight much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `protected var cR:CallResponder` in scope of `MyClass` and you define `var cR:CallResponder` in scope of function `callWS`. Try this:

```
public function callWS(ws:Myws):void{
    cR = new CallResponder();
    cR.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, resultHandler, false, 0, true);
    cR.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT, faultHandler, false, 0, true);
    cR.token = ws.MyCall(); 
}
```

Comment: Silly me, that was exactly my problem. Thanks